# react js getDerivedStateFromProps is calling continuously

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        myStateVar: []
    }
}

static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (props.myStateVar !== state.myStateVar) {
        return {
           myStateVar: props.myStateVar
        }
    }

    toggle() //Need to call the function each time when we get the props update
    return null;
}

toggle() {
    this.setState({
        otherStateVar: []
    })
}
```

I am migrating my react app from 16.3 to latest. I have a problem where getDerivedStateFromProps() is calling continuously because state is updating in toggle(). I need to call the toggle() when the props got updated

Help me out to resolve the problem.

Comment: You can use componentDidUpdate for this.

Comment: componentDidUpdate won't get the prop changes/updates right ?

Comment: componentDidUpdate will be called with prevProps as argument. You can check the condition there. I've added an answer which reflects it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use `componentDidUpdate` for this? It seems to me you can achieve the result by:

```
/**
 * @param {Props} prevProps props of the component
 **/
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.myStateVar !== this.props.myStateVar) {
    this.setState({ myStateVar: this.props.myStateVar });
    toggle();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`getDerivedStateFromProps` is run on every render. It is also a static method, so it shouldn't be called setState (or other non-static functions). In the documentation, React points out that most of the time you don't need this method to achieve state change based on prop changes [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#what-about-memoization).

So first option, don't call setState, it triggers a re-render and a re-render will run getDerivedStateFromProps. Essentially an infinite re-render loop.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (props.myStateVar !== state.myStateVar) {
        return {
           myStateVar: props.myStateVar,
           otherStateVar: [] // from toggle
        }
    }

    // Should not be called everytime this method runs. Only when props change
    // toggle() //Need to call the function each time when we get the props update
    return null;
}
```

Your other option is memoization which is covered pretty thoroughly in that link I provided.

Comment: thx for the reply. I have some calculations & functionality in toggle() and I need to update the state there based on calculation